# New line for input in Python

Tags: python

I am very new to Python programming (15 minutes) I wanted to make a simple program that would take an input and then print it back out. This is how my code looks.

```
Number = raw_input("Enter a number")
print Number
```

How can I make it so a new line follows. I read about using \n but when I tried:

```
Number = raw_input("Enter a number")\n
print Number
```

It didn't work.

Comment: "I read about using \n"... tell us what you read, in your own words.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Put it inside of the quotes:

```
Number = raw_input("Enter a number\n")
```

`\n` is a control character, sort of like a key on the keyboard that you cannot press.

---

You could also use triple quotes and make a multi-line string:

```
Number = raw_input("""Enter a number
""")
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw something like that but ignored it because in languages like C# whatever is in the quotes in printed exactly. Thanks anyways! This community seems really useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the input to be on its own line then you could also just

```
print "Enter a number"
Number = raw_input()
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this:

```py
    print("What is your name?")
    name = input("")
    print("Hello" , name + "!")
```

So when I run it and type Bob the whole thing would look like:

What is your name?

Bob

Hello Bob!

Answer (score 0):

```
# use the print function to ask the question:
print("What is your name?")
# assign the variable name to the input function. It will show in a new line. 
your_name = input("")
# repeat for any other variables as needed
```

It will also work with: `your_name = input("What is your name?\n")`

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please explain advantage of your solution, (And maybe how it work)

Answer (score -2):

in python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
'''
Read list of numbers and print it
'''
def enter_num():
    i = input("Enter the numbers \n")
    for a in range(len(i)): 
        print i[a]    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    enter_num()
```

Answer (score -3):

*In the python3 this is the following way to take input from user:*

**For the string:**

```
s=input()
```

**For the integer:**

```
x=int(input())
```

**Taking more than one integer value in the same line (like array):**

```
a=list(map(int,input().split()))
```

Comment: It does not answer the question. At all.